Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) MAUI app crash in release android net. 8, using forced screen orientation and concurrent GC
The setup is:

MAUI Android
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait set to the MainActivity.
Building in release.

At real physical device, using adb logcat -d > log.txt the following error can be seen:
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)
With those libs: libmonosgen-2.0.so, libmonodroid.so

It crashes in release only.
It doesn't matter how the screen orientation is set. (annotation or overriding onCreate)
Disabling "concurrent GC" fixes the issue.

I would like to know:

How to fix the crash,
Or if it cannot be done - is there another way to force screen orientation?
Or if it cannot be done - at least some reassuring words that this little fix I found is actually something harmless, and I wont have to pay for it in the future.


You can try to disable the Linker behavior option and try again. For more information, please check document: Linking a .NET MAUI Android app.

@JessieZhang-MSFT I disabled AOT compilation and the trimming, re-enabled the GC, and the problem did not show. The interesting part - I was able to reproduce it at will, and now even if I restore project file from the repo, It does work in release. I plan to leave my project in the state you recommended, accept my miracle and move on. If you add this as answer, I will accept it, thank you for your time.

Congrats and thanks for your feedback. And I have added this as answer based on your suggestion.   :)

You can try to disable the Linker behavior option and try again.
From document:Linking a .NET MAUI Android app,we could find that:

The linker enables you to trim your .NET MAUI Android apps. When
trimming is enabled, the linker leaves your assemblies untouched and
reduces the size of the SDK assemblies by removing types and members
that your app doesn't use.
Linker behavior can be configured for each build configuration of
your app. By default, trimming is disabled for debug builds and
enabled for release builds.

Besides, you can also try to disable AOT compilation and re-enabled the GC.
